# Debugging PL/SQL Procedure for reservation service report

Tags: oracle, plsql

For a school project, unable to figure out how to debug the code, I've managed to figure out that the problem is in this line of code: `Reservation_id:=: reservation_ID;` but I am unsure how to fix it

```
Set serveroutput ON;
Create or replace procedure Reservation_Services_Report (reservation_ID IN number)
As
Service_number reservation.service_type_id%type;
People_attending reservation.numb_people_attend%type;
Begin
Reservation_id:=: reservation_ID; 
Select s.service_name, s.service_type, s.service_type_food, s.service_type_entertainment, r.numb_people_attend from services s, reservation r 
where services.service_type_id = reservation.service_type_id;
Exception 
When no_data_found then 
dbm_output.put_line(‘No services for this reservation’);
End;
```

Comment: Identifiers in PL/SQL are not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it only it were your only problem!

- as you declared an IN parameter, why don't you use it? It is here to be **passed** to the procedure, not to accept it at runtime (which is what you planned to do with preceding its name with a colon).

  - besides, it is a good idea to distinguish parameter name from column name, otherwise you'll have problems as Oracle won't know which is which. That's why I renamed it to `par_reservation_id`
- `select` in PL/SQL requires `into` clause. In your case, you need to declare all those variables which match `select` column list. I named them all with the `l_` prefix (as a **l_**ocal variable); some people use `v_`; pick whichever you want, just try to stick to some *standards* - it'll make your code easier to read, debug and maintain
- `select` you wrote would probably return **too_many_rows** error as there's no restriction to number of rows; I presume you "forgot" to include the `where` clause so I put it there; I don't know whether it is correct or not as I don't have your tables. Fix it, if necessary
- when joining tables, try to switch to modern ANSI syntax and separate *joins* from (`where`) *conditions*, as I tried
- unless you're running that code in a tool that supports `dbms_output` to be displayed on the screen, you won't see anything. Exception is *handled* (kind of), but nobody will know what happened. Consider raising the error instead, e.g. `raise_application_error(-20000, 'No services for this reservation')`

Here's how the procedure might look like; hopefully, it is somewhat better than the original version. See if it helps.

```
Create or replace procedure 
  Reservation_Services_Report (par_reservation_ID IN number)
As
  l_service_name               services.service_name%type;
  l_service_type               services.service_type%type;
  l_service_type_Food          services.service_type_Food%type;
  l_service_type_entertainment services.service_type_entertainment%type;
  l_numb_people_attend         reservation.numb_people_attend%type;
Begin
  Select s.service_name, 
         s.service_type, 
         s.service_type_food, 
         s.service_type_entertainment, 
         r.numb_people_attend 
  into l_service_name,
       l_service_type,
       l_service_type_food,
       l_service_type_entertainment,
       l_numb_people_attend
  from services s join reservation r  on s.service_type_id = r.service_type_id
  where r.reservation_id = par_reservation_id;

Exception 
  When no_data_found then 
    dbms_output.put_line(‘No services for this reservation’);
End;
```